# MonoTouch Set Position from SubView

Tags: c#, .net, uiview, xamarin.ios, value-type

Hey Guys i´m new to MonoTouch and have a problem.
Can anyone of you tell me how to set the Position of a subview?
I tried this:

```
UIImageView imageview = new UIImageView(this.ImageSource);

this.AddSubview(imageview);

this.Subviews[0].Bounds.X = 30;
```

I hope anyone of you can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beside `Bounds` or `Frame` (mentioned by @Krumelur) there's a .NET issue in your code.

`RectangleF` is a value-type (struct), not a reference type. You cannot change their properties / fields in .NET without creating a new instance (directly or indirectly);

i.e. the property getter for `Bounds` will **always** return a new instance. So you assignment of 30 is done on an instance different than the one `Subviews[0]` is using.

**Proof:**

```
Console.WriteLine (Object.ReferenceEquals (this.Subviews[0].Bounds,
    this.Subviews[0].Bounds)); // prints 'False'
```

So what you need to do in such case is:

```
var bounds = this.Subviews[0].Bounds;
bounds.X = 30.0f;
this.Subviews[0].Bounds = bounds;
```

So the new `RectangleF` (struct) instance is assigned back to the `Bounds` property (with the new value you set).

Answer (score 2):

The `Bounds` property gives you, well, the bounds of the view.
If you want to reposition it, use:

```
var vourView = this.Subviews[0];
yourView.Frame = new RectangleF(new PointF(x, y), yourView.Bounds.Size);
```

or

```
yourView.Center = new PointF(newCenterX, newCenterY)
```