# Changing Frame, Size of UIImageView in UIScrollView Doesn't do anything

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to change the location of a UIImageView which I am placing inside of a UIScrollView.  No matter what I set, the Image always is shown in the upper left corner of the UIScrollView.  Trying to change the X,Y coords to something like 200,200 still places the image at 0,0.

MonoTouch Code:

```
    private void LoadPageContent(int page)
    {
        var panelScrollView = new UIScrollView();

        panelScrollView.MinimumZoomScale = 1.0f;
        panelScrollView.MaximumZoomScale = 3.0f;
        panelScrollView.MultipleTouchEnabled = true;

        panelScrollView.BackgroundColor=UIColor.Black;
        if (page == 1)
        {
            panelScrollView.BackgroundColor=UIColor.Red;
        }

        panelScrollView.ScrollEnabled = true;
        panelScrollView.UserInteractionEnabled=true;
        var ui = new UIImage (_assetImages[page], 1.0f, UIImageOrientation.Up);
        UIImageView imgView = new UIImageView(ui);

        //Position the panelScrollView in the right page on the main scrollview
        RectangleF frame = scrollView.Frame;
        PointF location = new PointF();
        location.X = frame.Width * (_numberOfPanels - 1);
        frame.Location = location;

        panelScrollView.Frame = frame;
        panelScrollView.BackgroundColor=UIColor.Green;

        imgView.Frame.X = 200; //<---- this does nothing
        imgView.Frame.Y = 200; //<---- this does nothing

    //Setting Bounds does nothing either

        imgView.ContentMode=UIViewContentMode.Center; //<--this does nothing

        panelScrollView.AddSubview(imgView);
        scrollView.AddSubview(panelScrollView);

    }
```

Any ideas??

Comment: That's how `struct` works on .NET. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7899415/220643 for details.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  Explain this code snippet in C# via VS.NET
I initialize a Point struct and I then go on to change it's X value and assert that x is now the new changed value.   
         
var p = new Point(1,1);
p.X = 5;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(p.X == 5);

Comment: 100% positive, see my proof on the link. `imgView.Frame.X = 200;` works by assigning `200` to `X` but it's a copy of the `imgView.Frame` (it's a *value-type*) that gets assigned (not the *reference* to the one in `imgView`). You get the same behaviour when using System.Drawing or System.Windows.Forms on Windows.

Comment: You are right.  I overlooked that.  Any thoughts about adding a compiler warning/error to MonoTouch for this like what exists in VS?  Or is it possible?

Comment: Content mode controls how image view positions the image inside it, not how it is positioned in its parent view.

Comment: In obj-c, you'd have to do this: `{ CGRect frame = imgView.frame; frame.x = 200; imgView.frame = frame ; }`... Try structuring it like that instead.